# php/javascript not working online

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have some code in php and javascript which is working on my computer, localhost, but is not working online. I use Godaddy and I called them. They said everything looks good on their end. They said they can't help with coding problems. I have a database containing some quotes. The function I'm trying to perform is to get a random quote from the database and display it on my webpage then change it to a new random quote every 10 seconds. I don't know anything about php or javascript. I paid someone to write this code and they said the code is good.

The javascript is:

```
var qouteobj=createRequestObject();
function getqoute(){
qouteobj.open("GET","php/randomquote.php",true);
qouteobj.send(null);
qouteobj.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(qouteobj.readyState==4 && qouteobj.status==200){
var q_rec=qouteobj.responseXML;
var rq=q_rec.getElementsByTagName('qoute');
var txt="";
var i;
for (i=0;i<rq.length;i++){
txt=txt + rq[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById('random-quote').innerHTML=txt;
setTimeout('getqoute()',10000);
setTimeout('getqoute()',10000);
}
}
```

The randomquote.php file is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<?php
include "connect.php";
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header("Pragma: no-cache" );

$sql = "SELECT quote FROM quotes where Rand() Limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$xml="<root>";
$xml.="<qoute>".$row['quote']."</qoute>";

$xml.="</root>";
echo $xml;
//echo $row['quote'];
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The html is simply:

```
<p id="random-quote"></p>
```

I know it's connecting to the database because I have other php code on the site that is working, pulling data from the database and displaying it on the page. The page is at: [www.bestmoviequote.com](http://www.bestmoviequote.com/) Thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: http://www.bestmoviequote.com/php/randomquote.php isn't returning anything. There's your problem.

Comment: When I view the file in my file manager it is showing the code

Comment: I know you are seeing the code, the problem is, the code isn't working as it is supposed to. There might be a problem in your connect.php

Comment: First you should'nt send headers before you did everything you had to do with the database. Then in your phpmyadmin, does `SELECT quote FROM quotes where Rand() Limit 1` gives you a result ?

Comment: http://www.bestmoviequote.com/php/connect.php isn't returning anything either but I know it's working because because I have other php code on the site that is working, pulling data from the database and displaying it on the page.

Comment: SELECT quote FROM quotes where Rand() Limit 1 does return a quote

Comment: Also, don't write things (like the xml tag) before sending headers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got it working. We also had a problem with the original code not displaying a truly random quote. It was favoring quotes with a higher amount of likes (I had another page where users could like the quotes.) The following solution fixed both problems.

Javascript:

```
var qouteobj=createRequestObject();
function getqoute(){
qouteobj.open("GET","/php/randomquote.php",true);
qouteobj.send(null);
qouteobj.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(qouteobj.readyState==4 && qouteobj.status==200)
{
var q_rec=qouteobj.responseText;
if (window.DOMParser)
{
parser=new DOMParser();
xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(q_rec,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async=false;
xmlDoc.loadXML(q_rec);
}
var rq=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("qoute");
var txt="";
var i;
for (i=0;i<rq.length;i++){
txt=txt + rq[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById('random-quote').innerHTML=txt;
setTimeout('getqoute()',10000);
}
}
}
```

randomquote.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "moviequotes";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header("Pragma: no-cache" );
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotes";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$rows=$result->fetch_row();
//$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$rndm=rand(1,$rows[0]);
$sql = "SELECT quote FROM quotes where id='".$rndm."' Limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$xml='<root>';
$xml.='<qoute>'.htmlspecialchars($row['quote']).'</qoute>';
$xml.='</root>';
echo $xml;
}
else
{
echo "Not working";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem comes from the fact you write things before sending headers.

try with that :

```
<?php
    include "connect.php";

    $sql = "SELECT quote FROM quotes where Rand() Limit 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);

header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header("Pragma: no-cache" );
$xml="<?xml version='1.0' ?>";
$xml.="<root>";
$xml.="<qoute>".$row['quote']."</qoute>";
$xml.="</root>";
echo $xml;
```

If there is still problems, please add `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` before the include of the connect script, and give us the errors

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` before the line `include "connect.php";` and give us the result.

Comment: I went on your site, it does work. 
`<?xml version='1.0' ?><root><qoute>"Whatever the mind of man can conceive and believe, it can achieve."</qoute></root>` from http://www.bestmoviequote.com/php/randomquote.php

Comment: It does not work anymore. add the `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and give us the error.

Comment: put the script I gave you, with the ini_set added, online. Then go to the page http://www.bestmoviequote.com/php/randomquote.php and give us the result